# Corda node data retrieval materialises into disk or local storage?

Tags: corda

When a Corda node retrieves the ledger data, will it materialize it into disk or local storage? If yes how is it be done to ensure it is secured?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the node's transactions and states are stored in the node's H2 database, and are not encrypted. This data is still secure, as no one else has access to your node.

In the future, Corda plans to support pluggable databases, so node owners won't be tied to H2 and can use any database they want. If the database you use supports encryption, there should be no problem using that in conjunction with Corda.